# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to change a picture box image

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to change the image of a `pictureBox` based on the number of occurance of a list:

```
list<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("Item1");
items.Add("Item2");
items.Add("Item3");
items.Add("Item4");
items.Add("Item5");

foreach (var item in items.OfType<string>().Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))
{
 int ItemNumber = item.i + 1;
 string ItemNumberStr = ItemNumber.ToString();
 PictureBox pbox = (PictureBox)this.Controls["Picturebox" + ItemNumberStr];
 pbox.Image = Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
 Label labl = (Label)this.Controls["label" + ItemNumberStr];
 labl.Text = item.x;
}
```

This is done within a `foreach` event in which `item.i` is the number of occurance represented as an `int`, then converted to a `string` to determine the number of `pictureBox` I'm trying to modify. But when I do this I recieve error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" here:

`pbox.Image = Properties.Resources.white_square_button;`

This also happens with the `label` aswell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is null here? pbox? Properties.Resources? Something else?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta "pbox"

Comment: It looks like you don't have an element defined with `this.Controls["Picturebox" + ItemNumberStr]`. Make sure that you have such element before trying to access its value.

Comment: I believe the problem might be your naming convention. Are you sure the controls are named Picturebox1 ... Picturebox5, letter-case matching? Also, if the controls are nested, in another container, they will not be visible in the parent.  If this is Windows Forms app, consider this.Controls.Find("PictureBox"+ItemNumberStr, true).

Comment: @Darek Did that and it indeed found the control i defined above.

Comment: is it "Picturebox"? or "PictureBox"?

Comment: @216 "Picturebox". I changed the name.

Comment: Sweet, @JoseCardama. glad I could help.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2):

[ControlCollection[String]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will not throw an exception if there are no control with such name:

```
        Control control = this.Controls["I am not here"];
        MessageBox.Show((control == null).ToString());
```

It is doubtful that `Properties.Resources` property is null, so the most probable is that the control you are trying to access do not exist or named a bit different.

Comment: The control is named exactly as I defined it.

Comment: Can you post the exact exception message you are getting? At which line, which object is null?

Comment: The problem is that pbox is taken as null I think `pbox null System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`

Comment: If `pbox` is null then it is not being named correctly or it hasn't been added to the Form.Controls collection. There is no other possibility short of some real problem in Form's framework code.

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The `PictureBoxes` I was trying to modify were in a `panel` and as mentioned here: [this.Controls doesn't contain all controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538788/this-controls-doesnt-contain-all-controls) by doing `this.Controls["Picturebox" + ItemNumberStr]` it would return me a null reference because the `PictureBoxes` were assigned to that label. So what I did is replace `this` with `panel1` (The name of the panel in which the `PictureBoxes` were) and now it works like a charm.

```
list<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Add("Item1");
items.Add("Item2");
items.Add("Item3");
items.Add("Item4");
items.Add("Item5");

foreach (var item in items.OfType<string>().Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))
{
 int ItemNumber = item.i + 1;
 string ItemNumberStr = ItemNumber.ToString();
 PictureBox pbox = (PictureBox)panel1.Controls["Picturebox" + ItemNumberStr];
 pbox.Image = Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
 Label labl = (Label)panel1.Controls["label" + ItemNumberStr];
 labl.Text = item.x;
}
```

Comment: change "this" to "groupBox1" fixed my problem, thanks